# Renaming .aspx file does not change inherits attribute (asp.net 4.0)

Tags: asp.net

I have to rename a file in the solution explorer.
I have made the following steps
Right click on the file and changed it to Login.aspx to Default.aspx.

 in .aspx in page directives the ***Inherits***  attribute doesn't change automatically.
 
 Does this means that When ever I rename a file I will have to change the Inherits attribute manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will have to change inherits attribute manually.